# Making a reshape function in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

Here's the code for a reshape function in Eigen. It works.

```
typedef MatrixXd mat;
typedef VectorXd vec;

Map<mat> reshape (vec b, const uint n, const uint m) {
    return Map<mat>(b.data(), n, m);
}
```

I was trying to decide the right type for the first argument.

`vec & b` still works, but I get strange errors with
`const vec & b` or `const vec b`:

```
error: invalid conversion from 'const Scalar* {aka const double*}' to 'Eigen::Map<Eigen::Matrix<double, -1, -1> >::PointerArgType {aka double*}' [-fpermissive]
     return Map<mat>(b.data(), n, m);
                 ~~~~~~^~
```

I suspect this is due to mutability and the fact that the reshape function doesn't allocate new memory, but I would like to learn a more detailed explanation.

Hmm, it seems that `vec && b` is the right type for this, but I'm out of my depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that it is a mutability issue. If you use `const vec&`, you can only map it to a `const mat` as

```
Map<const mat> reshape (const vec& b, const uint n, const uint m) {
    return Map<const mat>(b.data(), n, m);
}
```

otherwise you can modify the components of a const vec via the mapped matrix. It has nothing to do with allocating memory.

Actually both `vec` and `const vec` are wrong. Both of them mean mapping to a temp copy of the original vector, whose life ends after the function call, as Avi Ginsburg said, resulting in an undefined behavior.

**Please note the above code is only correct when the input is an `Eigen::VectorXd`.**

In fact both `vec&` and `const vec&` can be wrong, if your input `b` is an expression. Using `vec&` will fail compiling as the components of an expression are not mutable. Using `const vec&` will force the expression to be evaluated into a temp const vector during the function call and you are mapping to a temp vector again.

```
Map<mat> reshape (vec& b, const uint n, const uint m) {
    return Map<const mat>(b.data(), n, m);
}

Map<const mat> reshape_const (const vec& b, const uint n, const uint m) {
    return Map<const mat>(b.data(), n, m);
}

vec a(100), b(100);
Map<mat> c1 = reshap(a, 10, 10);                  // ok
Map<mat> c2 = reshap(a + b, 10, 10);              // error, expression not mutable
Map<const mat> c3 = reshap_const(a, 10, 10);      // ok
Map<const mat> c4 = reshap_const(a + b, 10, 10);  // error, mapping to temp vec
```

In this case you need to use the expression type as the parameter type, although you probably do not plan to use your `reshape` with expressions. You could find more details here.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html

Answer (score 2):

It's just a matter of scope. 
Let's create a MCVE and use that to explain:

```
#include <Eigen/Core>
#include <iostream>

using namespace Eigen;

typedef MatrixXd mat;
typedef VectorXd vec;

Map<mat> reshapeCopy (vec b, const size_t n, const size_t m) {
    return Map<mat>(b.data(), n, m);
}

Map<mat> reshape (vec &b, const size_t n, const size_t m) {
    return Map<mat>(b.data(), n, m);
}

int main()
{
    vec tr;
    tr.setLinSpaced(4,1,4);
    std::cout << tr << "\n\n";
    Map<mat> m = reshape(tr, 2,2);
    std::cout << m << "\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Using g++ 4.9.3 on Ubuntu outputs:

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4
>
> 4.94066e-324  3
>   4.94066e-324  4
>
> 1  3
>   2 4

In `reshapeCopy`,`b` is a *copy* of `tr`. Its lifetime is until the end of the `reshapeCopy` function. Therefore, when used in `main`, the output is gibberish/undefined behavior. In the `reshape` function `tr` is passed by reference and therefore the `b`s lifetime is as long as `tr` and the output is as expected.

[kangshiyin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38289479/2899559) is correct in pointing out that the specific error you're getting is when you define the function with `const vec b` or `const vec &b` that `b` is const, *i.e.*  not mutable, and the return type is a mutable `Map<mat>`.