# Extending Eigen with better syntax/naming

Tags: c++, eigen

I find Eigen's syntax more cumbersome than the other numerical linear algebra libraries I've worked with: numpy, MATLAB and armadillo. So I'm writing a bunch of "helper" functions, extending Eigen's syntax. (See [an earlier question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38288447/making-a-reshape-function-in-eigen))

My question is, hasn't this already been done?

I know that libigl [have added some MATLAB-esque function](https://libigl.github.io/libigl/matlab-to-eigen.html)s, but I'm wondering if there's more?

I'm trying not to reinvent the wheel here.

To give some examples:

`swap_rows(i, j)`, `swap_cols(i, j)`, `reshape`, coefficient-wise functions like `abs`, `log`, etc.

I'm trying to write more readable code.

Answer (score 1):

Matlab and numpy do not have the concept of expression, their function always work on a real matrix, either a matrix created by yourself or a temp buffer. Eigen on the other hand, uses template expressions to avoid temp memory buffer. It's functions should work both on matrices and expressions, that's probably why functions like `reshape` are not implemented. Eigen tends to leave the functions that require a temp buffer to users so that they can control when and where a buffer appears.

Coefficient-wise functions are already there. Please find more details in the following link.

http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__QuickRefPage.html

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not saying the stuff isn't there. I'm saying that the syntax is unappealing. I can't be the first person who doesn't want to write `myvec.array().abs()` when it could just as well be `abs(myvec)`. Same for `swap`: I find it a lot more difficult to parse `A.row(i).swap(A.row(j))` than `A.swap_rows(i, j)` or even `swap_rows(A, i, j)`.

I'm looking for a thin layer of nice syntax built on top of Eigen.

Comment: @krey `myvec.cwiseAbs()` will be better. About `.abs()` vs. `abs(...)`, I prefer the first one, as it is object-oriented. `A.row(i).swap(...)` is also object-oriented (starting with an object `A` rather than a command `swap`). It can also swap wtih any vector `...`, not just another row. Basically I think you cannot say whose syntax is better. You can only say whose syntax is more similar to Matlab.

Comment: OK, so I'm looking for something that makes it look more like MATLAB then ;)

Comment: (Off topic: I think that swapping two things belongs to both objects the same amount, so it should be a function `swap(a, b)`, rather than a method `a.swap(b)`)

Comment: @krey both OK. Python also support both `A.dot(B)` and `dot(A,B)`